# Interrupt a thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, future

I found this solution to know if a thread has been interrupted.

```
public class OurThread extends Thread(){
    private volatile boolean stop = false;
    public void run(){
        while (!stop) {
             //Do your actions
        }
     }
 }
```

But my run method is only executed once, so It doesnt make sense to put it insisde a while loop. Another approach I found, is to check the Thread.isInterrupted() flag, and then terminate the thread. My run() method is pretty long so I would have to check lots of times this condition making my code dirty.

I have to apply this into four diferents processes so im trying to find a simpler, cleaner soution. I was hoping if is there something like:

```
try{//my code}
catch(interrumption)
```

The problem is that since my thread is interrumped by using future.cancel(), the interruption is not thrown inside my run() code, then i cant do that either.

Any suggestion?
By now im checking lots of times between the code if the thread has been cancelled.
Thanks :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html There is also a static method of the `Thread` class, `Thread.interrupted()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, don't extend Thread, you should implement Runnable or Callable.

Secondly you can add a method like

```
static void checkInterrupt() {
    if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) 
         throw new IllegalStateException("Interrupted");
}
```

and place this in the four places.  This doesn't add much code and isn't as ugly as a task which won't stop.

Comment: +1. Perhaps explain that implementing `Runnable` is the alternative?

Comment: Also, why `IllegalStateException`?

Comment: It's a runtime instead of a check exception which you would have to declare or catch. Illegal State means that it cannot continue due to state, in this case the interrupt flag is set.

Comment: Im already implementing runnable, the problem is that future.cancel() attempts to interrupt my thread, but most of times it cant, then I have to interrupt it in a lower level

Comment: @PeterLawrey Neat, I like it.

Comment: If future.cancel doesn't interrupt your task, you are doing something wrong.  You should need to be attempting to access a thread directly.

Comment: By using future.cancel, I assume you are using an ExecutorService?

Comment: Is there any way to force a thread to stop, if future.cancel cant?

Comment: You can use Thread.stop() but it's a bad idea.  Much better to fix the code called so it stops when you tell it to.

Comment: and how can I know the reason it is not being interrupted. All Im getting is false after future.cancel()

Comment: It's not being interrupted because your code is ignoring it.  What you can do is take a thread dump with `thread.getStackTrace();` This will tell you where you need to add your check. ;)  I have written a monitor thread for some prejects which start dumping threads stacks to logs if they take too long.

Answer (score 1):

Your task ( Runnable or Callable) can't be interrupted unless it has inbuilt mechanism to respond to interrupts. Also it depends on your design; like, when exactly task expects to be interrupted. Usually we do when the task has reached a safe state.

So you check if interrupt is received and then respond appropriately. To reuse code you can use approach suggested by @Peter.

Comment: It is expected to end anytime. Im building a process's management panel, with the option to force a process to end.

Comment: You can divide your run method in multiple smaller modules or sub-tasks (i.e. into multiple run). this way it will be easy for you to check for interrupts and proceed only if its safe.

Comment: That is exactly what im trying to avoid. I need the process to end  immediately.

Comment: ill try that and see what happen